# Raspberry pi - Toggle SSH from terminal (without raspi-config)

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I want to have a physical toggle switch near my Raspberry pi 4, in order to turn on and off an SSH access, for security reasons. The Raspberry does not have a screen connected to it most of the times, so this is only for the situations I need to service it.

Currently the SSH is on by default, so I need to find a solution how to toggle it from my program in python (= command/sequence of commands)

I only found how to do it with `raspi-config`, but that has too many user interactions required, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything you want to do is to stop and start ssh you can use systemctl:

```
sudo systemctl start ssh
sudo systemctl stop ssh
```

If you don't want it to start at boot:

```
sudo systemctl disable ssh
```